# Facebook share button returns null url

Tags: javascript, facebook-sharer

I want to start by saying that everything was working ok last time I checked (like 2 months ago) but it seems like facebook changed something to their appi.

The URL sent back to the share form is NULL and also the count doesn't work anymore.

You can see the problem on [this page](http://www.tips4design.com/2010/08/tips-10-tips-that-will-help-you-win-on.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although still available, FB Share button was deprecated when facebook launched like button. Like button contains the sum of likes, shares and messages of URL. FB like button is easier to implement. Can you check here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

Comment: Yes, it looks like it only works in Firefox. It's strange that it was working a month ago.

Comment: The preview for the like button is pretty buggy and also the design doesn't fit in the space the share button was. Lal, in Firefox that dev page works ok, I guess that Facebook doesn't really like Google.

Comment: I had this same problem. Then I changed to Like button with Layout Style box_count and Show Faces = false, to layout compatibility.

Comment: Yes, I did that too, but had to get the code with Firefox cause changing styles or fonts in chrome did not work (the widget stayed unchanged).